# How do I calculate load resistance?

Tags: resistance, thevenin, load

I'm here with yet another problem. This time I can't figure out what the question wants. I've calculated the Thévenin equivalent, however I can't work out how I should calculate the RL.

Is the load resistance the same as the Rth?

Here is my Thévenin equivalent schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNiMcK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is the original question:

[image]

Comment: It looks like you have completed the question to me. You have the Thevenin equvalent circuit there. You have Vth, Rth and a load. That seems to be all the question was asking. Although I think that is the first question I have seen where current is measured in Ohms! Lol

Comment: Haha, I saw that too. I think my professor was a bit sleepy when submitting the question.  

Comment: Remember, for Thevenin equavalent, to open circuit current sources and to short circuit voltage sources.

Answer (score 1):

From the look of the question, it looks like all you were asked to do is to solve the circuit into the Thevenin equivalent. By that, it means reducing the circuit so it just has Rth and Vth with a load.

An example of a Thevenin equivalent circuit:

[image]

The image is taken from [HERE](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-10/thevenins-theorem/). The page also has an example of solving a circuit to a Thevenin equivalent.

You don't need to do any more. The criteria of the question as written has been satisfied.