# How to calculate maximum power when value of load resistance is unknown?

Tags: power, resistors, thevenin, load

Once again same circuit and same voltage source / current source and resistances. However now I need to calculate the maximum power that is consumed by the R<sub>L</sub>. How do I do that, and most importantly when I don't have the value on the load resistor?

Here is the shematic of the previous problem I solved (Thévenin equivalent):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGbtyy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

And the new question is this one:

[image]

**Note:  I<sub>1</sub> should be 2 mA.**

And here is the link to the question I submitted before this one:

[How do I calculate load resistance?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/490294/how-do-i-calculate-load-resistance/490298#490298)

Comment: I1 is not 2 mΩ (well not in this universe anyway)

Comment: Yes, you are correct. It's 2 mA.

Comment: Please fix your question then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The power in the load resistor is:  $$P_L= I^2R_L$$

$$I=\frac{V}{R_{th}+R_L}.$$

Therefore:

$$ P_L=(\frac{V}{R_{th}+R_L})^2R_L.$$

To obtain the maximum power, differentiate and assign zero to obtain maximum:

$$\frac{d P_L}{dR_L}=0 \text{ therefore } R_L=R_{th}  ~~~~~~\text{(NB.)}$$

This gives $$P_{max} = \frac{V^2}{4\cdot R_{th}}.$$

Comment: I think you've misread the question.

Comment: No, I have not, I just skipped the middle part that he should practice.

Comment: Once again, how can I calculate all of this when the RL is unknown?

Comment: Follow the above step-by-step.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't figure out how I can solve the first step when I have 2 unknowns ( PL and RL) to begin with?

Comment: Keep the symbols unknown and follow the reasoning!  In the end \$P_L\$ and  \$R_L\$ are not required.